# validate pandas dataframe values against dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas, error-handling

I want to convert a csv file to a pandas dataframe, and on input I would like to validate the values of the csv file against a dictionary of sorts.

For example, the only accepted values in the csv file for the column color are 'red', 'yellow', and 'green'. If there's a row in the csv that lists color as 'purple', I'd like to continue processing the csv into a pandas dataframe, but have an error be thrown. I'd like to do this for all columns in a dataframe and still be able to work with the dataframe, just have the errors thrown so I know if there's something that violates the data dictionary I have. Something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
error: "There's purple in here!"

color_sort = df.sort(columns= "color")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother doing that just load the whole csv in as is and then post-process the column values:

```
In [32]:
valid_colours = ['red','green','blue']
df = pd.DataFrame({'colours':['black', 'red', 'purple', 'blue','green']})
df

Out[32]:
  colours
0   black
1     red
2  purple
3    blue
4   green

In [33]:    
df['valid'] = df['colours'].isin(valid_colours)
df

Out[33]:
  colours  valid
0   black  False
1     red   True
2  purple  False
3    blue   True
4   green   True
```

The reason is because checking row by row when reading in your csv is slow whilst doing the above will be a vectorised approach and much quicker

Comment: Hi! This is great. Way more efficient than what I had been expecting. If I wanted to run this just to check if any of the values returned False, how could I do that? I'm getting errors with: `if df['colours'].isin(valid_colours) == False:
    print "Error: invalid colour found"`

Comment: Think I just solved my own issue here :)
`if df['colours'].isin(valid_colours).all():
    print "No errors"
else:
    print "color error"`